# Keeping the initial value of a variable in recursive function

Tags: python, variables, recursion

I am writing a recursive function that will take two strings `sub` and `string`. I have to find out if `sub` is a substring of `string`.

A recursive function is a strict requirement which can't be removed.

This is what I have tried, but its broken:

```
def is_substring(sub,string):
    if sub=="":
        return True
    if string=="":
        return False
    if sub[0]==string[0]:
        return is_substring(sub[1:],string[1:])
    if sub[0]!=string[0]:
        return is_substring(sub,string[1:])
```

It returns `True` instead of `False` when:

```
sub='misip'
string='mississippi'
```

Comment: Can you please paste your code here?

Comment: The code you have posted is recursive already (?)

Comment: yes but if you look at the image i posted it doesn't work properly

Comment: nick there is a hyperlink at the and there

Comment: Do not post a link to an image. Post the code *here*, as *text*.

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Hyperlinks can be used to _enhance_ your question, but the core info _must_ be posted in the question itself. Questions that need external links to make sense are _not_ acceptable on SO.

Comment: there was a long question before that so i thought showing that might help you, but i wont do that anymore, thanks for the feedback

Comment: @AhmetDaraVEFA You may edit it right now.

Comment: I assume you are doing this as an exercise in recursion, since you can easily test if `s1` is a substring of `s2` with `s1 in s2`.

Comment: Thankyou for fixing your question. That's much better!

Comment: yes indeed @PM2Ring , however i still don't have a solid answer to my question

Comment: BTW, it's not a good idea to use `string` as a variable name as that shadows the name of the standard `string` module, which contains several handy string constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to preserve the initial value of an argument to a recursive function is to use an additional keyword argument. It's conventional to give this argument a default value of `None` so callers of the function don't need to initialize this argument, but when the function calls itself recursively it gets set appropriately, when required.

For example:

```
def is_substring(sub, string, oldsub=None):
    if sub == "":
        return True
    if string == "":
        return False

    if oldsub is None:
        oldsub = sub

    if sub[0] == string[0]:
        return is_substring(sub[1:], string[1:], oldsub)
    else:
        return is_substring(oldsub, string[1:], oldsub)
```

Another way to preserve the value is to create a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) by defining the recursive function inside a wrapper function, like this:

```
def is_substring(sub, string):
    oldsub = sub
    def is_substringR(sub, string):
        if sub == "":
            return True
        if string == "":
            return False

        if oldsub is None:
            oldsub = sub

        if sub[0] == string[0]:
            return is_substringR(sub[1:], string[1:])
        else:
            return is_substringR(oldsub, string[1:])

    return is_substringR(sub, string)
```

This function implements the same algorithm as the earlier version. And I'm pretty sure that's the algorithm you're trying to implement with your code. Unfortunately, this algorithm doesn't find substrings correctly.

So here's a recursive `is_substring` that *does* work correctly, but it doesn't need to preserve old argument values.

```
def is_substring(sub, string):
    if sub == "":
        return True
    if string == "":
        return False

    if string.startswith(sub):
        return True
    else:
        return is_substring(sub, string[1:])

# some tests

data = (
    ('misip', 'mississippi'),
    ('tle', 'cattle'),
)

for sub, target in data:
    print('{!r} {!r} {}'.format(sub, target, is_substring(sub, target)))
```

**output**

```
'misip' 'mississippi' False
'tle' 'cattle' True
```

If you don't want to use the `.startswith` method, you can use slicing instead:

```
def is_substring(sub, string):
    if sub == "":
        return True
    if string == "":
        return False

    if sub == string[:len(sub)]:
        return True
    else:
        return is_substring(sub, string[1:])
```

---

As I said in the comments, the usual way to do a substring test is to use the `in` operator, which calls the string's `.__contains__` method.

```
sub in string
```

Comment: thank you for the awesome answers, i was trying to do it without using the in and len operators, thank you again, much appreciated.

Comment: @AhmetDaraVEFA No worries. FWIW, I tried a bunch of variations, trying to find a purely recursive version that tests character by character, but the logic was getting ridiculously complicated, and I _still_ couldn't get it to work correctly in all cases. So I ended up ditching that frustrating exercise and going with the compromise versions using `string.startswith(sub)` and `sub == string[:len(sub)]`. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a parameter of you function that never change something like :

```
def recur(completeString, string ) :
    if string :
        print string
        recur(completeString, string[:-1])
    else :
         print "Nothing left from '{}'".format(completeString)

recur("hello", "hello")
```

This will output :

```
hello
hell
hel
he
h
Nothing left from 'hello'
```

Comment: this might work but i have to look into it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your initial call and your later calls have slightly different logic.  On failure, your initial call can simply advance to the next character in **string**; your later calls have to start over from the beginning of **sub**.

I suggest two functions for this: a wrapper function to make the first comparison and preserve the given interface (or can you change it?), and a second that will look for a continuous match to the end.

Here's a possible solution with tracing print statements inserted (and commented out).

```
def match_all(sub, string):
    # print "ENTER ALL", sub, string
    if sub == "":
        # print "ALL empty sub; success"
        return True
    if string == "":
        # print "ALL empty str; fail"
        return False
    if sub[0] == string[0]:
        # print "ALL head match: recur"
        return match_all(sub[1:],string[1:])
    else:
        # print "ALL head diff: fail"
        return False

def is_substring(sub,string):
    # print "ENTER TOP", sub, string
    if sub == "":
        # print "empty sub; success"
        return True
    if string == "":
        # print "empty str; fail"
        return False
    if sub[0] == string[0]:
        # print "head match: recur"
        if match_all(sub[1:],string[1:]):
            return True
    # print "head diff: recur"
    return is_substring(sub,string[1:])

print is_substring("misip", "mississippi")
# print "------------"
print is_substring("sip", "mississippi")
```

Note that logic change: the main function looks for immediate results, but still continues if it finds no such resolution.  The support function looks only for an immediate match at this string position.